# Flutter : high watermark memory limit exceeded problem

Tags: android, ios, flutter, memory-limit

I am fetching some posts with image with infinite scroll. It's a simple app. But when scrolling down, after some post app has crashed. Note: I am using Getx, pagination_view,transparent_image,http packages.

> here is my homescreen.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<PaginationViewState> paginationKey =
        GlobalKey<PaginationViewState>();
    return GetBuilder<PostController>(
        init: PostController(),
        initState: (state) {
          Get.put(PostController()).fetchAllPostsList(0);
        },
        builder: (postCtrl) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Here some another widgret"),
                  PaginationView<PostDetailsModel?>(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    key: paginationKey,
                    paginationViewType: PaginationViewType.listView,
                    //  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    pageFetch: postCtrl.fetchAllPostsList,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        PostDetailsModel? postDetails, int index) {
                      return MainPostWidgetScreen(
                        postDetails: postDetails,
                      );
                    },
                    pullToRefresh: true,
                    onError: (dynamic erro) => const Center(
                        child: Text(
                            "Something Went to wrong") //Image.asset(CustomIcon.error),
                        ),
                    onEmpty: const Center(
                      child: Text("No TimeLine Post Avaialable"),
                    ),
                    bottomLoader: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    initialLoader: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

here is my mainpostWidget

```
class MainPostWidgetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final PostDetailsModel? postDetails;
  const MainPostWidgetScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.postDetails,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<PostController>(
        init: PostController(),
        builder: (postCtrl) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        //   ProfileImageWidget(
                        //      imageUrl: postDetails!.updatedBy!.avatar),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              postDetails!.isPostedByOther!
                                  ? RichText(
                                      text: TextSpan(children: [
                                      TextSpan(
                                        text: "",
                                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                          ..onTap = () {
                                            // SharedDataManageService()
                                            //     .getUserID()
                                            //     .then((ownUserId) {
                                            //   print(ownUserId);
                                            //   print(
                                            //       postDetails!.createdBy!.id);
                                            //   if (ownUserId !=
                                            //       postDetails!.createdBy!.id
                                            //           .toString()) {
                                            //     print("object");
                                            //     PageNavigationService
                                            //         .generalNavigation(
                                            //       "/FriendProfileScreen",
                                            //       arguments: postDetails!
                                            //           .createdBy!.id
                                            //           .toString(),
                                            //     );
                                            //   } else {
                                            //     ApiErrorHandleService
                                            //         .handleStatusCodeError({
                                            //       "code": 404,
                                            //       "message": "It's you",
                                            //     });
                                            //   }
                                            // });
                                          },
                                      ),
                                      const TextSpan(
                                        text: " > ",
                                      ),
                                      TextSpan(
                                        text: "",
                                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                          ..onTap = () async {
                                            // await SharedDataManageService()
                                            //     .getUserID()
                                            //     .then((ownUserId) {
                                            //   print(ownUserId);
                                            //   print(postDetails!.updatedBy!.id);
                                            //   if (ownUserId !=
                                            //       postDetails!.timelineOwner!.id
                                            //           .toString()) {
                                            //     PageNavigationService
                                            //         .generalNavigation(
                                            //             "/FriendProfileScreen",
                                            //             arguments: postDetails!
                                            //                 .timelineOwner!.id
                                            //                 .toString());
                                            //   } else {
                                            //     ApiErrorHandleService
                                            //         .handleStatusCodeError({
                                            //       "code": 404,
                                            //       "message": "It's you",
                                            //     });
                                            //   }
                                            // });
                                          },
                                      )
                                    ]))
                                  : InkWell(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        // await SharedDataManageService()
                                        //     .getUserID()
                                        //     .then((ownUserId) {
                                        //   if (ownUserId !=
                                        //       postDetails!.updatedBy!.id
                                        //           .toString()) {
                                        //     PageNavigationService
                                        //         .generalNavigation(
                                        //             "/FriendProfileScreen",
                                        //             arguments: postDetails!
                                        //                 .updatedBy!.id
                                        //                 .toString());
                                        //   } else {
                                        //     ApiErrorHandleService
                                        //         .handleStatusCodeError({
                                        //       "code": 404,
                                        //       "message": "It's you",
                                        //     });
                                        //   }
                                        // });
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        "",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "${postDetails!.createdAt} .",
                                  ),
                                  Icon(
                                    postDetails!.privacy == 1
                                        ? Icons.public
                                        : postDetails!.privacy == 2
                                            ? Icons.people_alt_outlined
                                            : Icons.lock_outlined,
                                    size: 15,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    // GetBuilder<ProfileController>(
                    //     init: ProfileController(),
                    //     builder: (profileCtrl) {
                    //       return Visibility(
                    //         visible: postDetails!.createdBy!.id !=
                    //             profileCtrl.myProfile.value!.id,
                    //         child: InkWell(
                    //             onTap: () {
                    //               Get.dialog(CupertinoAlertDialog(
                    //                 title: const Text(
                    //                   "Alert!",
                    //                 ),
                    //                 content:
                    //                     const Text("Really report this post ?"),
                    //                 actions: [
                    //                   CupertinoButton(
                    //                       child: const Text("Cancel",
                    //                           style: CustomTextStyle
                    //                               .normalBoldStyle),
                    //                       onPressed: () {
                    //                         PageNavigationService.backScreen();
                    //                       }),
                    //                   CupertinoButton(
                    //                       child: const Text(
                    //                         "Report",
                    //                         style: CustomTextStyle
                    //                             .normalBoldStyleErrorColor,
                    //                       ),
                    //                       onPressed: () {
                    //                         PageNavigationService.backScreen();
                    //                         postCtrl
                    //                             .reportAPost(postDetails!.id);
                    //                       }),
                    //                 ],
                    //               ));
                    //               //  postCtrl.reportAPost(postDetails!.id);
                    //             },
                    //             child: const Icon(Icons.do_not_touch)),
                    //       );
                    //     })
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      postDetails!.content ?? "",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                postDetails!.images!.length == 1
                    ? Container(
                        width: Get.width,
                        //   height: double.infinity,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Image.network(
                          postDetails!.images?[0].path ?? "",
                          //  height: double.infinity,
                          width: Get.width,
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Wrap(
                        runSpacing: 5.0,
                        spacing: 10.0,
                        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                        children: postDetails!.images?.map((imagePath) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                width: Get.width / 2.5,
                                height: Get.width / 2.5,
                                child: FadeInImage(
                                  placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
                                  image: NetworkImage(imagePath.path ?? ""),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      postDetails!.totalLikes! > 0
                          ? Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                const Icon(
                                  Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined,
                                  size: 16,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "${postDetails!.totalLikes}",
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      postDetails!.totalComments! > 0
                          ? Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                const Icon(
                                  Icons.mode_comment_outlined,
                                  size: 16,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  postDetails!.totalComments! > 1
                                      ? "${postDetails!.totalComments} comments"
                                      : "${postDetails!.totalComments} comment",
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        // postCtrl.tryToLikeUnlikeaPost(postDetails!.id);

                        // if (postDetails!.isLiked!) {
                        //   postDetails!.isLiked = false;
                        //   postDetails!.totalLikes =
                        //       postDetails!.totalLikes! - 1;
                        // } else {
                        //   postDetails!.isLiked = true;
                        //   postDetails!.totalLikes =
                        //       postDetails!.totalLikes! + 1;
                        // }
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Text(
                              postDetails!.isLiked! ? "Liked" : "Like",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: const [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.mode_comment_outlined),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Comment",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

> here is my controller

```
class PostController extends GetxController {
    Future<List<PostDetailsModel?>> fetchAllPostsList(
    int offset,
  ) async {
    try {
      return await PostApiService().getAllPostListRequest(offset);
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('error $e');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint("$e");
    }
    return [];
  }
}
```

> here is my API service

```
class PostApiService {
 
  Future<List<PostDetailsModel?>> getAllPostListRequest(
    int offset,
  ) async {
    // String? token = await SharedDataManageService().getToken();

    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        "https://api-backend.khelahobe.com.bd/api/v2/no-auth-post?offset=$offset&item_limit=20");

    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      // 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Charset': 'utf-8'
    };
    MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'GET',
      url,
    );

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    StreamedResponse streamedResponse =
        await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));

    var respStr = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

    //  debugPrint(json.decode(json.encode(respStr.body)));

    var response = json.decode(respStr.body);
    if (respStr.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = respStr.body;
      var decoded = json.decode(jsonResponse);

      List<PostDetailsModel?> mapdatalist = decoded["posts"]
          .map<PostDetailsModel?>((b) => PostDetailsModel.fromJson(b))
          .toList();

      return mapdatalist;
    } else {
      throw {
        "code": respStr.statusCode,
        "message": response["message"],
      };
    }
  }
}
```

> here is my model

```
class PostDetailsModel {
  int? id;
  int? privacy;
  String? content;
  List<Images>? images;
  bool? hasVideo;
  bool? isLiked;
  int? totalLikes;
  int? totalComments;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  bool? isPostedByOther;
  String? uuid;

  PostDetailsModel(
      {this.id,
      this.privacy,
      this.content,
      this.images,
      this.hasVideo,
      this.isLiked,
      this.totalLikes,
      this.totalComments,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.isPostedByOther,
      this.uuid});

  PostDetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    privacy = json['privacy'];
    content = json['content'];
    if (json['images'] != null) {
      images = <Images>[];
      json['images'].forEach((v) {
        images!.add(Images.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    hasVideo = json['has_video'];
    isLiked = json['is_liked'];
    totalLikes = json['total_likes'];
    totalComments = json['total_comments'] ?? 0;
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    isPostedByOther = json['is_posted_by_other'];
    uuid = json['uuid'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['privacy'] = privacy;
    data['content'] = content;
    if (images != null) {
      data['images'] = images!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['has_video'] = hasVideo;
    data['is_liked'] = isLiked;
    data['total_likes'] = totalLikes;
    data['total_comments'] = totalComments;
    data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    data['is_posted_by_other'] = isPostedByOther;
    data['uuid'] = uuid;
    return data;
  }
}

// class TimelineOwner {
//   int? id;
//   String? name;
//   String? gender;
//   String? level;
//   String? badges;
//   String? address;
//   String? avatar;
//   String? cover;

//   TimelineOwner(
//       {this.id,
//       this.name,
//       this.gender,
//       this.level,
//       this.badges,
//       this.address,
//       this.avatar,
//       this.cover});

//   TimelineOwner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
//     id = json['id'];
//     name = json['name'];
//     gender = json['gender'];
//     level = json['level'];
//     badges = json['badges'];
//     address = json['address'];
//     avatar = json['avatar'];
//     cover = json['cover'];
//   }

//   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
//     final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
//     data['id'] = id;
//     data['name'] = name;
//     data['gender'] = gender;
//     data['level'] = level;
//     data['badges'] = badges;
//     data['address'] = address;
//     data['avatar'] = avatar;
//     data['cover'] = cover;
//     return data;
//   }
// }

//
class Images {
  int? id;
  String? path;

  Images({this.id, this.path});

  Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    path = json['path'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['path'] = path;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is very simple app, then why has it crashed ? When it has crashed, it showed  me that type of error in iOS

```
* thread #19, name = 'io.worker.1', stop reason = EXC_RESOURCE (RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY: high watermark memory limit exceeded) (limit=2098 MB)
    frame #0: 0x00000001fe6270a8 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove + 88
libsystem_platform.dylib`:
->  0x1fe6270a8 <+88>:  stnp   q0, q1, [x3]
    0x1fe6270ac <+92>:  add    x3, x3, #0x20
    0x1fe6270b0 <+96>:  ldnp   q0, q1, [x1]
    0x1fe6270b4 <+100>: add    x1, x1, #0x20
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

In Android, it just but no error show on log.